# c++ linker error and undefined reference when accessing static constexpr member

Tags: c++, g++, constexpr

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <array>

struct S {
    static constexpr std::array<int,5> sca = {1,2,3,4,5};

    static constexpr int foo(size_t i) {
        return sca[i];
    }
};

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    S s;
    return s.foo(4);
}
```

Compiling this gives me a linker error and an `undefined reference`:

```
$ g++ --std=c++14 -O0 -o test1 test1.cpp 
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccfZJHBY.o: warning: relocation against `_ZN1S3scaE' in read-only section `.text._ZN1S3fooEm[_ZN1S3fooEm]'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccfZJHBY.o: in function `S::foo(unsigned long)':
test1.cpp:(.text._ZN1S3fooEm[_ZN1S3fooEm]+0x1a): undefined reference to `S::sca'
/usr/bin/ld: warning: creating DT_TEXTREL in a PIE
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I checked my g++ version it turned out to be 11.3:

```
$ g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu 11.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.3.0
...
```

The strangest thing is: this code compiles fine in CompilerExplorer with x86-64 gcc 11.3: https://godbolt.org/z/rjG31z9hY

So I thought that maybe it is a compiler version issue, but compiling with g++-12 yielded the same result:

```
$ /usr/bin/g++-12 --std=c++14 -O0 -o test1 test1.cpp
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccH1PFkh.o: warning: relocation against `_ZN1S3scaE' in read-only section `.text._ZN1S3fooEm[_ZN1S3fooEm]'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccH1PFkh.o: in function `S::foo(unsigned long)':
test1.cpp:(.text._ZN1S3fooEm[_ZN1S3fooEm]+0x1a): undefined reference to `S::sca'
/usr/bin/ld: warning: creating DT_TEXTREL in a PIE
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

$ /usr/bin/g++-12 --version
g++-12 (Ubuntu 12.1.0-2ubuntu1~22.04) 12.1.0
...
```

I found out that it works with `--std=c++17` and with `-O1`:

```
$ g++ --std=c++14 -O1 -o test1 test1.cpp 
$ ./test1 
$ echo $?
5

$ g++ --std=c++17 -O0 -o test1 test1.cpp 
$ ./test1 
$ echo $?
5
```

I have also found out that binding the result of `foo` to a variable on the stack somehow fixes the issue:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    S s;
    constexpr int x = s.foo(4);
    return x;
}
```

And allows this code to be built and executed without changing compilation flags:

```
$ g++ --std=c++14 -O0 -o test2 test2.cpp 
$ ./test2 
$ echo $?
5
```

Why does it behave like that?

Comment: The compiler explorer cannot build your code. You have not checked the compiler output option "Link to binary" https://godbolt.org/z/ocWdoG43x

Comment: @273K thank you for this piece of the answer. Now I can finally be satisfied.

Answer (score 2):

I found a part of the answer in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43194989/5202246).

But why it works in CompilerExplorer is still a mystery to me as well as why binding it to a variable on stack fixes the issue.

Edit 1: CompilerExplorer

As [273K](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6752050/273k) wrote in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75954528/c-linker-error-and-undefined-reference-when-accessing-static-constexpr-member?noredirect=1#comment133967358_75954528), I forgot to check the compiler output option "Link to binary".

Comment: This is more fitting for an update to the question than posting as answer at this point. If the link was a complete you would close as a duplicate, answering wouldn't be appropriate. But it's not a match and doesn't really answer the question, so it's not a good answer.

Comment: @user4581301 for me a 1/3 of the answer is better than 0/3 of the answer for now. I was going to update it when I find more info.

Answer (score 2):

Regardless of which of your variations we look at `sca[i]` in `foo` odr-uses `sca`. (You don't even need to call `foo` at all for this to be the case.) As a result a definition for `sca` must be available. However, if none is available the program is *ill-formed, no diagnostic required* (IFNDR), meaning that the compiler *may* issue a diagnostic for the problem, but doesn't have to.

Practically speaking, it is just a matter of whether or not the compiler optimized the access to `sca` away by inferring what value you would read from it instead of actually calling `foo`. Since `foo` is also implicitly `inline` the compiler doesn't *have to* emit a definition for it (but some compilers do), so whether or not there will be a reference to `sca` in the object file for the linker to resolve will depend on optimization and compiler/linker specifics.

Before C++17, `static constexpr std::array<int,5> sca = {1,2,3,4,5};` is not a definition of `sca` and so your program is IFNDR. All compilers you tried are behaving correctly. There doesn't need to be any warning or error for this. A definition `std::array<int,5> S::sca;` must be added after the class definition to make the program well-formed.

Since C++17 `static constexpr std::array<int,5> sca = {1,2,3,4,5};` is a definition (because the `constexpr` makes it implicitly `inline`) and the program is well formed in either variation. Again, the compilers are behaving correctly. Before C++17 there were no `inline` static data members at all, so `constexpr` couldn't imply it.

Comment: That is a valuable insight, thank you